# change primeng PanelMenu styles

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm trying to change the style of PanelMenu component

I have changed the global background color.

[image: Menu]

I would change the main menus colors to white and keep submenus to black

Also on focus on an element change the color from blue to another color

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [multiple]=false></p-panelMenu>
```

CSS

```
::ng-deep .ui-panelmenu .ui-widget {
    background-color: #5F5F5F !important;
    font-family: 'BNPPSans'
}
::ng-deep .ui-menuitem-text {
    font-family: 'BNPPSans';
};
```

I have tied many combinations refering to the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu) but no one was working
In dev tool I can change it here

[image]

But by copying it to css no changes are made

```
::ng-deep .ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header.ui-state-active, .ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header.ui-state-active a{
    background-color: red !important;
};
```

Here's a [stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-lamdv2?file=app/app.component.css) ( I don't know why the items are overlapping  )

Comment: Can you create a Plunker please ?

Comment: I have added a plunkr

Comment: Do you load your custom CSS after the one from PrimeNG ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
::ng-deep body .ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header.ui-state-active > a:hover{
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
  }
  :host >>>
  ::ng-deep .ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header.ui-state-active > a {
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid  rgb(212, 210, 210); 
  }
  :host >>>
  ::ng-deep .ui-panelmenu .ui-panelmenu-header.ui-state-active > a:hover {
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid  rgb(212, 210, 210); 
  }
```